# Backups in Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, backup, availability-groups

In case of async commit setup and the backup preference set to secondary replica.
I have observed, in case of high unsent log size, log backup on secondary replica starts failing for that database with error:

> Connection With Primary Replica Not Active

The unsent log size was `~4GB`. There was no connectivity issues.

What factors impact log backups in multiple secondaries and async commit mode?

Comment: Which DBMS and/or tool(s) are you using that give you this error? This question is pretty meaningless without that information.

Comment: This is the error we get in SSMS, with the normal backup command. BAckup log <dbname> to disk = '<path>'

Comment: What is SSMS? Please update your question to include name of DBMS and tool and tag for them too.

Comment: You need to first verify that your secondary replica is in a SYNCHRONIZING state.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup on any secondary replica if they are connected to the primary replica AND the state is either SYNCHRONIZED or SYNCHRONIZING.

It seems that you should check the connection to the primary replica. Please take a look in the sql server's error log.